# Wordpress Pagination wp_link_pages Amend Next URL

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm paginating my posts in Wordpress using the  shortcode and wp_link_pages function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_link_pages/

However, when the user reaches the end of the post, I wanted to continue on to the next article. For example:

```
www.example.com/new-post
www.example.com/new-post/1
www.example.com/new-post/2
www.example.com/new-post/3 (end of post) 
www.example.com/next-post
www.example.com/next-post/1
www.example.com/next-post/2
```

This is my current code which currently only does the pagination using Next and previous. I've tried many ways to add this functionality with no success yet.

```
$defaults = array(
    'before'           => '<div id="pagination_wrap">' . __( '', 'twentyfourteen' ),
    'after'            => '</div>',
    'link_before'      => '<div class="pagination_btn">',
    'link_after'       => '</div>',
    'next_or_number'   => 'Next',
    'separator'        => ' ',
    'nextpagelink'     => __( 'Next' ),
    'previouspagelink' => __( 'Previous' ),
    'pagelink'         => '%',
    'echo'             => 1
    );
    
    wp_link_pages( $defaults );
```

Has anyone tried this before?

EDIT: While probably not perfect, this works.

```
    global $page, $pages;
        
        the_content();
    
        if ($page == count($pages)) { 
        //Link To Next Article
        }
        else
        { 
        $defaults = array(
        'before'           => '<div id="pagination_wrap">' . __( '', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'after'            => '</div>',
        'link_before'      => '<div class="pagination_btn">',
        'link_after'       => '</div>',
        'next_or_number'   => 'Next',
        'separator'        => ' ',
        'nextpagelink'     => __( 'Next' ),
        'previouspagelink' => __( 'Previous' ),
        'pagelink'         => '%',
        'echo'             => 1
        );
    
        wp_link_pages( $defaults );
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone, this is a working solution to this question.

```
global $page, $pages;
    
    the_content();

    if ($page == count($pages)) { 
    //Link To Next Article
    }
    else
    { 
    $defaults = array(
    'before'           => '<div id="pagination_wrap">' . __( '', 'twentyfourteen' ),
    'after'            => '</div>',
    'link_before'      => '<div class="pagination_btn">',
    'link_after'       => '</div>',
    'next_or_number'   => 'Next',
    'separator'        => ' ',
    'nextpagelink'     => __( 'Next' ),
    'previouspagelink' => __( 'Previous' ),
    'pagelink'         => '%',
    'echo'             => 1
    );

    wp_link_pages( $defaults );
```